# 50% off Dollar Bill Machine in Bioshock Infinite "Vending Empty"

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I'm in the Hall of Heroes and found a 50% off dollar bill vending machine. However the machine says "Vending Empty" when I walk up to it. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Anyone else run into this and know why it doesn't work?

Comment: I *think* it's supposed to be empty. It's been empty for me in all of my play throughs. =(

Comment: Well, considering that he's covered in what appears to be tar and that he looks quite damaged, I'd say he was assaulted by the Vox Populi and robbed blind. Well, he might have sold out beforehand though; who wouldn't jump at the occasion to buy some 50%-off ammo to defend against the Vox (except the Vox themselves, of course)?

Comment: If I ever find a dollar bill vending machine that's selling dollar bills at 50% off, it'll be empty pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I played through this section, this machine had one or two items for sale. They weren't standard Dollar Bill items, but Minute Man's Armory items, i.e., weapon upgrades. Perhaps if you've already bought the upgrades somewhere else, there isn't anything available to sell you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same thing on my playthrough.  When I was on the return trip back through this area, it was selling a limited selection of items.

Answer (score 0):

The 50% off is only for the Clip Increase for the pistol. If you already bought it before reaching the tear, it will be empty.